# Is there a way to have instant spell check in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

Much like most word processors have spell check as I type, is there a way to have this done in InDesign?

I'm constantly forgetting to run the spell check before sending off proofs and I'm getting a reputation :/

Comment: :) was "teputation" intentional?

Comment: No, but you can see why I need spell check lol

Comment: This post just saved my job. I am always making typos and miss spellings when I have to re-type things and I don't catch them before sending it off to the next person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Preferences > Spelling**, check Dynamic Spelling and set the options you like.

You can also enable **Preference > Autocorrect** which may be helpful as well. However, be a bit wary of autocorrect. It can easily autocorrect to the wrong word depending on your typing error.... it will spell correctly... but it may spell the wrong word entirely.

Comment: Yep. I had a boss who was trying to write an email to someone saying, "I look forward to **working** with you." She missed the K, and the email program corrected her to "I look forward to **whoring** with you." Fortunately she caught it before it went out...